# How can I see the contents of a USB drive through cmd?

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line

Can't boot into Windows. I am trying to replace certain files in the `system32/drivers` folder from cmd through the bootable installation disc.

The files I want to use are on a USB driver. I basically I want to first make sure the files are there, so I would like to see the contents of the USB drive through the cmd. And then I want to take someone files from the drive and push them into the drivers folder. The drivers folder already contains files with a similar named. I want to replace those file.

Comment: Get / make a bootable USB Key and put the driver on this bootable key. Boot with the USB Key and then you can see the drivers you wish to try to install in the non-working system.

Comment: I thought once you make to USB bootable, that's the only thing it's good for.

Comment: You should be able to make a folder on the bootable drive and put the driver files you need in that folder

Answer (score 0):

I recommend going to https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10 and downloading the Windows 10 installer.

You'd need to open the file on another computer, and install a bootable windows 10 media onto a USB.

Then, simply plug the usb into the broken laptop/computer, go through the setup and choose to keep your files (if you want to keep your files).

Now, to boot onto the usb just turn on the computer, then turn it off again once you see the computers make appear on the boot screen.
Do the above until it says something about Advanced Recovery.

Now, press advanced options and boot from the usb from there.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This goes into full detail of what John commented.